# Atlantis with self-signed certificate

Tags: automation, terraform, atlantis

I have set up Atlantis tool in order to automate Terraform activities on Gitlab.
It works on http, but I have problems if I setup https.

I receive the following error when I test the webhook on Gitlab:*Hook execution failed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=<my_ip_address> state=error: tlsv1 alert internal error*

I am using directly the IP address, not a domain name.

I am new to HTTPS mechanisms. What am I missing here?

I have:

- set up the Atlantis server flags --ssl-key-file and --ssl-cert-file
- generated a self-signed certificate with the following code: `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -subj "/CN=<IP_address>"`
- opened FW rules on port 4141 (the one that I am using) and 443
- used "https" instead of "http" in the webhook URL

Comment: In order for https to work correctly, you must use domain name to connect and your cert should be signed by a trusted provider.

Comment: is a domain name mandatory? I've read that for test purposes a self-signed certificate can be used (atlantis accepts it through flags).

Comment: It's mandatory for SSL to work without ignoring SSL errors (sometimes called insecure mode). SSL certs have a "common name" that says what they are signing for, and this a domain name for https.